# GET request with Path Parameter in RestAssured API Testing

Tags: java, api, get, rest-assured, path-variables

I have tested my API Through Postman

GET - https://url:8332/v1/agreement/:agreementId?agreementType=posted
If I use abouve url in postman I am getting result what I expected.

Where

- https://url:8332 is API Link
- v1/agreement is an endpoint
- :agreementId is **path variabl**e - value is account number so dev made the api in a way that we can pass account number but can not see in url
- agreementType is queryparam

Now I am trying automate this test using RestAssured
code:
String url = "https:/url:8332/v1/agreement";
String apiUrl = url + "/agreementId";

given().pathParam("agreementId", "1234").queryParam("agreementType","CHQ").when().get(apiUrl).then().log().body();

I am getting error like Invalid number of Path Parameters, Expected 0 and was 1. Redundant path parameter are agreementId=1234.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this

```
given().log().all()
       .pathParam("agreementId", "1234")
       .queryParam("agreementType", "CHQ")
       .when()
       .get("https://localhost/v1/agreement/{agreementId}");
```

See the log:
[image]